# Django UserProfile slug field

Tags: django, django-models, slug

I'm looking to create a url to visit a user profile using a `slug`. Ie. I want to visit `/profile/myname` to bring up my user profile. What I am having difficulties with is implementing the `slug` field for a user model.

Additionally, not sure if this matters or not but I have created a `UserProfile` model which extends the standard `User` model as shown below:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from autoslug import AutoSlugField


class UserProfile(models.Model):

  user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='profile_name')
  about_me = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
  slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='User.username', default='', unique=True)
```

which gives the error (when trying to migrate):

```
DETAIL:  Key (slug)=() is duplicated.
```

I believe the urls to be correct but have included it for reference (in an app named profile):

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)', views.detail, name='detail')
```

Comment: Do you already have an existing migration for your UserProfile? If so, please show it. And provide the command line command by which you try to migrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you already have some records in `userprofile` table with empty/null values in `slug` field. Because you've marked that field as `unique=True` it can only have one field with empty value. To avoid this error, delete the records with empty value in slug field, or just assign them a unique slug and you'll be good to go.

And as you can understand from above, having `default=''` in a field that has `unique=True` wont work. Unique means unique, even `''` as an empty value is considered a unique value and can be used in just one row if you have `unique=True`. That also means you cannot have any default value in a unique field.